# How do I know if my php process has right permissions to write to a file?

Tags: php, linux, apache, error-logging

I turned on error logging in php.ini file.

```
error_log `/etc/httpd/logs/error_log`

error_reporting `22527`
```

I try triggering an error by using [trigger_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) function. However, nothing gets written to the file. File is not even created. I'm guessing there are permission errors but how can I tell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php

> ```
> bool is_writable ( string $filename )
> ```
>
> returns TRUE if the filename exists and is writable.

That being said, logs generally go in `/var/log/` or `/var/apache2/log` or somewhere other than `/etc/` as

> [/etc](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/etc.html)
>
> This is the nerve center of your system, it contains all system related configuration files in here or in its sub-directories

**If you mess something up in `/etc/` it will be really, really bad.**